# Euler characteristic of a union of planes

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Let $P_1 ,...,P_5$ be mutually distinct planes in $\Bbb{R}^3$ such that:

- the intersection of any distinct 2 is a line.
- the intersection of any distinct 3 is a point.
- the intersection of any distinct 4 is an empty set.

Let $X=\bigcup_{i=1} ^5 P_i$ with the topology as a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^3$

What is the Euler characteristic of $X$?

I guess I'm getting a bit confused since I usually try to visualize stuff in $\Bbb{R}^3$ but I'm having trouble here. I can only think of a triangle prism or an open box, but in both cases there are planes with no intersection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An amazing fact of nature is that the Euler characteristic is ***the*** *homotopy invariant, signed mesure* such that $\chi(\ast) = 1$. In particular it satisfies the rule : $$\chi(\mathrm A \cup \rm B) = \chi( \rm A) + \chi(\rm B) - \chi(\rm A \cap \rm B)$$

Comment: Using this formula for $\chi(\rm A_1 \cup ... \cup \rm A_5)$, I find that the answer is 5.

Comment: I tried it this way, but I'm also getting 4. Looking to see if I made a mistake.

Comment: My calculus is $5 - \rm C_5^2 + \rm C_5^3$.

Comment: I'm not sure I get that notation, does $C_5^2$ correspond to $\chi (A_1\bigcap A_2) + $... while the other to the intersections of 3?
In which case, wouldn't it be $5-4+3$?

I'm sorry if I'm missing something really simple here.

Comment: $\rm C_n^i$ is the binomial coefficient. My formula is just that $\chi(\rm A_1 \cup ... \cup \rm A_n) = \chi(\rm A_1) + ... + \chi(\rm A_n) - \chi(\rm A_1 \cap \rm A_2) - ... - \chi(\rm A_{n-1} \cap \rm A_n) + \chi(\rm A_1 \cap \rm A_2 \cap \rm A_3) + ...$

Comment: Then we are indeed talking about the same, but I'm still getting $C_5 ^2 = 4$ and $C_5 ^3 = 3$ so $5-C_5 ^2+C_5 ^3 = 4$

Comment: Nope, these two coefficients are the same by symmetry, both equal to 10.

Comment: I'm seeing what I was doing wrong now... nevermind then, 5 it is. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, not yet an answer, but just a guess!

Using hands on calculations, I get the answer $4$. There is certainly no doubt that, upon translating the planes with some affine automorphism, we can safely restrict ourselves to the situation where $P_1=\lbrace x=0\rbrace,~P_2=\lbrace y=0\rbrace,~P_3=\lbrace z=0 \rbrace,~P_4=\lbrace x+y+z=2\rbrace$.

Setting $P_5$ to be the plane passing through the points $(1,0,1),(0,1,1),(0,-1,0),(-1,0,0)$ you get a figure that should be homotopy equivalent to a tetrahedron with a plane intersecting it horizontally at midheight, and a smaller tetrahedron attached to it along an edge. This figure has $12$ faces, $17$ edges and $9$ vertices, so its Euler caracteristic is $4$.

Comment: I see my mistake: $P_3\cap P_4\cap P_5=\emptyset$ in my example...